# POST HTTP method having 500 Internal Server Error on Apache and Django2 production

Tags: django, apache, centos7

I'm having an error regarding my POST method not working on production for Apache and Django2 project

[image]

The network tab is showing error, but there are no details regarding the error

[image]

I already have the code for POST as Views, and here is the code for the Views:

```
**views.py:**
class Smoke(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'add/index.html')

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return JsonResponse(
        {
            "message": "Successfully Added",
            "details": data
        },
        status=200
    )
```

Also, here is the code for the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('add/', Smoke.as_view({'get', 'post'}), name='smokeping-add'),
]
```

Is there anything I needed to do in order for the POST method to work properly in Fetch API?

```
fetch('',{
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

Comment: This code is working on development but on production integrated with Apache, POST Method is not working.

Comment: You need to show the content of the 500 response from the developer console.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm still new to Django, can you tell me where should I check that one?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django. You showed an error from the browser dev console. The network tab should show the full content of the error response.

Comment: It may be due to CSRF token, have you resolved csrf for js ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I check the error on the dev console, and it's just a simple error regarding internal server error.

Comment: @PankajSharma I disabled the CSRF middleware in order to proceed without it. And still having an error.

Comment: Hello Guys, there was an error on the module that I written. Due to some ascii codec that was not working on wsgi module. :) Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

You may set DEBUG to True in your settings file and view error details. But don't forget to turn it off later :)
P.S. Have you considered installing nginx->uwsgi instead of Apache?

Comment: Please use comments in order to ask for clarifications.